# How to bind a command to Hyperlink in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I know I can create a handler to RequestNavigate event with the following code:

```
private static readonly ProcessStartInfo s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo = new() { UseShellExecute = true };
private void PreviewLink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo.FileName = e.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    using (Process.Start(s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

The code above works perfectly. But if I use the same code but with a command, it will throw a System.InvalidOperationException: "Failed to convert resource to object.":

```
public ICommand PreviewLinkNavigateCommand => new RelayCommand(obj =>
{
    s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo.FileName = PreviewLink.NavigateUri.AbsoluteUri;
    using (Process.Start(s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo)) { } // throws a System.InvalidOperationException: "Failed to convert resource to object."
});
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBlock Padding="10 0 10 0">
    <Hyperlink x:Name="PreviewLink" FontSize="14" 
               NavigateUri="{Binding SelectedMedia.Source.AbsoluteUri}"
               Command="{Binding PreviewLinkNavigateCommand}">
        Preview link
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

RelayCommand:

```
internal class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object?> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object?, bool>? _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object?> execute, Func<object?, bool>? canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter) => _canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    public void Execute(object? parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Comment: You should bind the destination URI to the `Hyperlink.CommandParameter` when you are using a command to navigate. Where the exception is thrown.?

Comment: @BionicCode **Thank you! It works**. But why if I use `NavigateUri` instead of `CommandParameter` it will throw a `System.InvalidOperationException`? An exception is thrown in `Process.Start(s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo)`

Comment: Difficult to tell. Knowing the actual resource path that has failed to convert could help. You could try to use the Uri.OriginalString property instead of the AbsoluteUri property (AbsoluteUri prepends the resource type to the path). For testing purposes, you should "hardcode" the resource path into the XAML Hyperlink.NavigateUri property. Then try both variants (event and command) again. Your current code is not enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @BionicCode No matter what property I use `OriginalString` or `AbsoluteUri`. In the event handler it works the same good. In the `Command` it throws an exception. But if I bind `Command` with the `CommandParameter` it works perfectly: 
`public ICommand PreviewLinkNavigateCommand => new RelayCommand(obj =>
{
    s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo.FileName = (string?)obj;
    using (Process.Start(s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo)) { }
});`. I think the `CommandParameter` works something the same like `e.Handled = true` or something. Btw thank you for your reply to my problem. I am satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BionicCode have said I should bind a Command with a CommandParameter as uri.

**.xaml.cs:**

```
private static readonly ProcessStartInfo s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo = new() { UseShellExecute = true };
public ICommand PreviewLinkNavigateCommand => new RelayCommand(obj =>
{
    s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo.FileName = (string?)obj;
    Process.Start(s_previewLinkProcessStartInfo)?.Dispose();
});
```

**.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Padding="10 0 10 0">
    <Hyperlink x:Name="PreviewLink" FontSize="14" 
               Command="{Binding PreviewLinkNavigateCommand}"
               CommandParameter="URI">
        Preview link
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you or can you not just have it directly written into the XAML? (*used google as an example but you can also put file paths in and they will work*)

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Hyperlink RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate"
               NavigateUri="https://www.google.co.uk/">Google</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e) => Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: I've told that the event handler works perfectly for me. I want to use Command parameter instead of handler. BionicCode has already solved my problem in the comment section.